# Hive partition columns seem to prevent "select distinct"

Tags: distinct, hive, partitioning, hiveql

I have created a table in Hive like this:

```
CREATE TABLE application_path
    (userId STRING, sessId BIGINT, accesstime BIGINT, actionId STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Running on this table the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM application_path;
```

gives the expected result:

```
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user3@domain.com
...
```

Then I've changed the declaration to add a partition:

```
CREATE TABLE application_path
    (sessId BIGINT, accesstime BIGINT, actionId STRING)
PARTITIONED BY(userId STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Now the query SELECT DISTINCT userId... runs for seconds as before, but eventually returns anything.

I've just noticed the syntax:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS application_path;
```

but I was wondering if that's the only way to get unique (distinct) values from a partitioning column. The output of SHOW PARTITION is not even an exact replacement of what you would get from SELECT DISTINCT, since the column name is prefixed to each row:

```
hive> show partitions application_path;            
OK
userid=user1@domain.com
userid=user2@domain.com
userid=user3@domain.com
...
```

What's strange to me is that usedId can be used in GROUP BY with other columns, like in:

```
SELECT userId, sessId FROM application_path GROUP BY userId, sessId;
```

but does return anything in:

```
SELECT userId FROM application_path GROUP BY userId;
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue, it will be fixed in 0.10
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2955